# Procedimiento almacenado con parámetros de salida retorna NULL

Tags: sql-server

Siempre retorna dbNULL, no encuentro el error
Desde ya muchas gracias, espero sus respuestas

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ESTADISTICAS 
@Fecha_i DATE,
@Fecha_f DATE,
@TVENTAS FLOAT OUT,
@NVENTAS INT OUT,
@NPRODUCTOS INT OUT,
@DCAJA FLOAT OUT
AS
BEGIN
SET @TVENTAS=(SELECT SUM(monto_t) FROM Venta WHERE Venta.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_i AND @Fecha_f AND estado=1);
SET @NVENTAS=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Venta WHERE Venta.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_i AND @Fecha_f AND estado=1);
SET @NPRODUCTOS=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Producto);
DECLARE @N INT;
SET @N=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Dinero_Disp);
SET @DCAJA=(SELECT monto FROM Dinero_Disp WHERE (id=@N ))
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega un select al final,antes del `END`, con los campos que deseas retornar:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ESTADISTICAS 
@Fecha_i DATE,
@Fecha_f DATE,
@TVENTAS FLOAT OUT,
@NVENTAS INT OUT,
@NPRODUCTOS INT OUT,
@DCAJA FLOAT OUT
AS
BEGIN
SET @TVENTAS=(SELECT SUM(monto_t) FROM Venta WHERE Venta.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_i AND @Fecha_f AND estado=1);
SET @NVENTAS=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Venta WHERE Venta.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_i AND @Fecha_f AND estado=1);
SET @NPRODUCTOS=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Producto);
DECLARE @N INT;
SET @N=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Dinero_Disp);
SET @DCAJA=(SELECT monto FROM Dinero_Disp WHERE (id=@N ))


SELECT @TVENTAS,@NVENTAS,@NPRODUCTOS,@N,@DCAJA


END
```

Comment: Muchas graciass

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, el procedimiento es bastante ineficiente y propenso a errores en la consulta de @DCAJA. Dejo algo un poco más robusto y más orientado al pensamiento de bases de datos.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ESTADISTICAS 
    @Fecha_i DATE,
    @Fecha_f DATE,
    @TVENTAS FLOAT OUTPUT,
    @NVENTAS INT OUTPUT,
    @NPRODUCTOS INT OUTPUT,
    @DCAJA FLOAT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @TVENTAS = SUM(monto_t),
           @NVENTAS = COUNT(*)
    FROM Venta 
    WHERE Venta.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_i AND @Fecha_f 
    AND estado=1;

    SELECT @NPRODUCTOS = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Producto;

    SELECT TOP 1 
            @DCAJA = monto 
    FROM Dinero_Disp 
    ORDER BY id DESC;

END
GO
```

Ahora, el problema puede ser la forma en la que se llama el procedimiento, ya que hay que especificar cuales parámetros regresarán valores. Dejo el ejemplo de como hacerlo directamente en SQL Server.

```
DECLARE 
    @Fecha_i DATE = '20200201',
    @Fecha_f DATE = '20200228',
    @TVENTAS FLOAT ,
    @NVENTAS INT ,
    @NPRODUCTOS INT ,
    @DCAJA FLOAT;

EXEC SP_ESTADISTICAS @Fecha_i    = @Fecha_i
                    ,@Fecha_f    = @Fecha_f 
                    ,@TVENTAS    = @TVENTAS    OUTPUT
                    ,@NVENTAS    = @NVENTAS    OUTPUT
                    ,@NPRODUCTOS = @NPRODUCTOS OUTPUT
                    ,@DCAJA      = @DCAJA      OUTPUT;

SELECT @TVENTAS 
      ,@NVENTAS 
      ,@NPRODUCTOS
      ,@DCAJA;
```

Sin embargo, si se quisiera una solución más pura y regresar un conjunto de datos que es lo que deberían de regresar los procedimientos almacenados en vez de depender de variables, se puede reescribir así.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ESTADISTICAS 
    @Fecha_i DATE,
    @Fecha_f DATE
AS
BEGIN
    WITH cteVentas AS(
        SELECT TVENTAS = SUM(monto_t),
               NVENTAS = COUNT(*)
        FROM Venta 
        WHERE Venta.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_i AND @Fecha_f 
        AND estado=1
    ),
    cteProductos AS(
        SELECT NPRODUCTOS = COUNT(*) 
        FROM Producto
    ),
    cteDinero_Disp AS(
        SELECT TOP 1 
                DCAJA = monto 
        FROM Dinero_Disp 
        ORDER BY id DESC
    )
    SELECT v.TVENTAS,
           v.NVENTAS,
           p.NPRODUCTOS,
           d.DCAJA
    FROM cteVentas AS v
    CROSS JOIN cteProductos AS p
    CROSS JOIN cteDinero_Disp AS d

END
GO
```